# Trying to send simple messages with zeromq in python between two hosts

Tags: python, zeromq

Script running on machine 1

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
print "socket bound"

while True:
    print "Waiting for message"
    message = socket.recv()
    print "message received: " + str(message)
```

This script gets to the socket.recv() and then never returns from that call.

The process that sends the data runs on machine2

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
print "socket created"
socket.connect("tcp://machine2:5000")
print "socket connected"

for i in range(1, 3):
    print "About to send " + str(i)
    socket.send("Hello " + str(i))
    print "Sent " + str(i)

print "About to close socket"
socket.close()

print "Socket closed"
```

Executes to completion, but never finishes...

```
$ python bar.py
socket created
socket connected
About to send 1
Sent 1
About to send 2
Sent 2
About to close socket
Socket closed
```

I'm obviously doing it wrong, how do I create a 'queue' to receive multiple messages from publishes on remote hosts?

Comment: I haven't used 0mq yet but what I notice is that on machine one you connect to local host and on machine 2 you connect to machine2. Should you not be connecting to machine 1 on machine 2 ?

Comment: Do you have the networking set up right?  i.e. is the hostname right?  is port 5000 on the receiver reachable?

As an illustration, you can replace machine2 with machinethatdoesntexist and see if you still get the same output from the sender.

Comment: The machines can talk to each other over the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to bind the socket properly and set option using setsockopt as given below. It will be fine..

```
import zmq
import socket



context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

socket.bind("tcp://*:5000")
print "socket bound"

while True:
    print "Waiting for message"
    message = socket.recv()
    print "message received: " + str(message)
```

Comment: Thank you. When you do the setsocketopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ""), are you telling zmq that you want to subscribe to everything?

Comment: Thank you. What is the usage of `setsockopt` please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example with PUB binding and SUB connecting - start the publisher first and then the subscriber:

pub.py

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
print "socket created"
socket.bind('tcp://*:5000')
print "socket connected"

channel = '1001'
i = 0
while True:
    message = 'Hello %s' % i
    socket.send("%s %s" % (channel, message))
    print "Published: %s " % message
    time.sleep(0.5)
    i += 1

print "About to close socket"
socket.close()
print "Socket closed"
```

sub.py (replace publisher with appropriate hostname/IP):

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
channel = '1001'
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'channel')
socket.connect('tcp://publisher:5000')
print "socket connected"

while True:
    print "Waiting for message"
    message = socket.recv()
    print "message received: ", message
```

Comment: it is not true that PUB needs to bind and SUB connect - zeromq does not care about connections direction or order.

Comment: Removed note on PUB bind/SUB connect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I need to make one socket a PULL socket and the other a PUSH socket.

Comment: if you want to use PUSH/PULL, replace zmq.SUB by zmq.PULL, zmq.PUB by zmq.PUSH and bind as: 
socket.bind("tcp://*:5000")